# How to properly get user's PATH environment variable in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I'm building an application (Windows only) that needs to modify user's PATH variable. At some moment, it will add new directories to PATH, and other moment it will remove those directories from PATH.

I'm using the `exec` method (from `child_process`) to run the `setx` command to set the environment variable. So, this is fine.

The problem is when I need to retrieve the PATH variable. I've tried to run `echo %PATH%`, to get the current %PATH%, and `reg query HKCU\Environment /v Path`, to get the current PATH from the registry. Both methods are returning different results, and both results aren't the expected.

For example, when I run `echo %PATH`, it returns the user's PATH variable, prepending the current application binary directories (like node_modules.bin) (I think this behaviour occurs because Node.JS is prepending some PATH="blablabla" to the command when running the application).

[image: example running echo %PATH%]

And, when I run `reg query HKCU\Environment /v Path`, it returns, I believe, the "original" user's PATH variable, without any third-party software directories. This is strangely different from the result I get when opening regedit and checking the content of that key, or opening system's environment variables interface and checking the paths inside PATH (both methods have the "C:\local.host\modules\bin", "C:\local.host\modules\nvm\1.1.11" and "C:\local.host\modules\nodejs" directories, that aren't on result presented by NodeJS).

[image: example querying from registry]
[image: viewing the user's PATH variable using system tools]

This could be more strange when I run the same command from a command prompt window, that returns the correct user's PATH, with third-party directories.

[image: querying from registry using command prompt]

So, what's the problem? I need to retrieve the user's PATH variable (like seen in system tools - regedit, command prompt and env. variable editor), but echoing the %PATH% or querying from registry from Node aren't returning the expected result.

How can I properly get the user's PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. Maybe not the perfect one, but is working as expected.

The concept is to get the %PATH% envvar from normal CMD (using `exec` and running `echo %PATH%`), then removing all paths that have "node_modules". Also, I've checked that NodeJS "dumps" the real %PATH% into the application, where it's appends the node_modules directories, so I needed to keep the `process.env.PATH` variable updated with my modifications, **but including the node_modules ones**.

The final solution looks this way:

```js
const appPath = process.env.PATH.split(";").filter((segment) => segment.trim().length > 0).filter((segment) => segment.indexOf("node_modules") > -1);

export function getPath(callback){
    exec(`echo %PATH%`, (err, stdOut, stdErr) => {
        let data = stdOut.trim();
        let pathArray = data.split(";").filter((segment) => segment.trim().length > 0);
        let uniquePathArray = [];

        pathArray.forEach((path) => {
            if(uniquePathArray.indexOf(path) == -1 && appPath.indexOf(path) == -1){
                uniquePathArray.push(path);
            }
        });

        if(callback){
            callback(uniquePathArray);
        }
    });
}

export function setPath(pathArray, callback){
    let systemPath = pathArray.join(";");
    let envPath = [...appPath, ...pathArray].join(";");

    process.env.PATH = envPath;

    exec(`setx PATH "${systemPath}"`, (err, stdOut, stdErr) => {
        if(err == null){
            if(callback){
                callback(stdOut);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

First, I stored the directories that contains "node_modules" into an `appPath` array, that I "subtract" when getting the %PATH% variable. Also, when setting the %PATH%, I'm prepending the `appPath` into the %PATH% variable, **but** only for the `process.env.PATH`, while the system's %PATH% doesn't need that paths.

I've made a helper to manage system's envvars (Windows only), which you can find on this link: https://gist.github.com/RBFraphael/dcd3385c8e18a885345d364cff0f3e2f

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this npm package written by my   [@camol/winreg-rs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@camol/winreg-rs)

```js
const { JsRegistry } = require("@camol/winreg-rs");

let registry = new JsRegistry('HKCU');

const value = registry.getKeyValue("Environment", "Path");

registry = null;

console.log({value})
```